# zeep.exceptions.TransportError: Server returned HTTP status 404 (no content available)

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, http-status-code-404, zeep

Trying to run my code I get a zeep.exceptions.TransportError: Server returned HTTP status 404 (no content available).

I am using my school's soap api (i think - wsdl + rest = ???). It is located at `https://cms.powerschool.com/pearson-rest/services/PublicPortalServiceJSON?wsdl`

Under this, there is a login object I want to call. A dump of zeep shows me that this is
`login(username: xsd:string, password: xsd:string, userType: xsd:int) -> return: ns2:ResultsVO`

Finally, this is my code. Error on the last line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import zeep, requests
def createClient(base_url):
    if base_url[:-1] != "/":
        base_url += "/" 
    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth("pearson","m0bApP5")
    url = base_url + "pearson-rest/services/PublicPortalServiceJSON?wsdl"
    return zeep.Client(wsdl=url,transport=zeep.transports.Transport(session=session))

client = createClient("https://cms.powerschool.com")

login = client.service.login(username="YYYYY",password="XXXXX",userType=2)
```

What could cause this?